# Spring Webflux Security Filterchain JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver with jwt converter

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, spring-webflux

I have a simple Security filter chain configured for multitenancy. However, I cannot add my customer jwtConverter.

Here is the setup

```
 @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,  Converter<Jwt, Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>> jwtAuthenticationConverter) {
        JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver authenticationManagerResolver =
                JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver
                        .fromTrustedIssuers("issuer1", "issuer2");

        http
                .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .authorizeExchange(spec -> spec
                        .pathMatchers(
                                "/api/v1/profile/public/**",
                                "/api/docs/**",
                                "/swagger/**"
                        ).permitAll()
                        .anyExchange()
                        .authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver));
        return http.build();
    }
```

When I add jwtConverter

```
 .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 ->
                        oauth2
                                .jwt(jwtSpec -> jwtSpec.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter))
                                .authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver)

                )
```

I'm getting an error **If an authenticationManagerResolver() is configured, then it takes precedence over any jwt() or opaqueToken() configuration**

How do I resolve this in spring webflux 3.2.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a bit of cross checking on past raised github issues on the same, I've managed to  create a custom `JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver` with a `CustomAuthenticationManager` that has `authenticate` method which can be extended to allow a customAuthentication converter.

Here is my solution

**Simple CustomAuthenticationConverter**

```
public class CustomAuthenticationConverter {
    private static final String ROLES = "roleName";
    private static final String ROLE_PREFIX = "ROLE_";

    public Mono<Authentication> convertJwtToAuthentication(Jwt jwt) {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = extractAuthoritiesFromJwt(jwt);
        return Mono.just(new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities, jwt.getClaimAsString("userPublicId")));
    }

    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthoritiesFromJwt(Jwt jwt) {
        var realmRoles = realmRoles(jwt);

        return realmRoles
                .stream()
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    private List<String> realmRoles(Jwt jwt) {
        return Optional.of(ROLE_PREFIX.concat(jwt.getClaimAsString(ROLES)))
                .map(List::of)
                .orElse(emptyList());
    }
}
```

**CustomAuthenticationManager**

```
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements ReactiveAuthenticationManager {

    private final ReactiveJwtDecoder decoder;

    public CustomAuthenticationManager(ReactiveJwtDecoder decoder) {
        this.decoder = decoder;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        // Implement custom authentication logic here
        BearerTokenAuthenticationToken token = (BearerTokenAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        Mono<Jwt> jwtMono = decoder.decode(token.getToken());

        return jwtMono.flatMap(jwt -> new CustomAuthenticationConverter().convertJwtToAuthentication(jwt));
    }
}
```

**JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver**

```
@Bean
    public JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver jwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver() {
        Map<String, ReactiveAuthenticationManager> managers = new HashMap<>();
        for (String issuer : trustedIssuers) {
            ReactiveJwtDecoder decoder = ReactiveJwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(issuer);
            managers.put(issuer, new CustomAuthenticationManager(decoder));
        }
        return new JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver(issuer -> Mono.justOrEmpty(managers.get(issuer)));
    }
```

**The add the resolver in SecurityWebFilterChain**

```
.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.authenticationManagerResolver(jwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver()));
```

And ofcourse you'd need to have a list of `trustedIssuers`.